# Как забрать ссылку на сайт в телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Нужно чтобы при переходе в телеграмм бота забиралась ссылка на сайт с которого перешли в бота, и эта ссылка отправлялась в личные сообщения тому кто перешел в бота. как это реализовать?

Comment: Deep linking что-ли? Можно получить ссылку на бота, например `https://t.me/<bot>`. [Можно в ссылку указать текст, что бот сможет получить](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/eaae662636fac822d2b92f889df7a5f56db3dcbe/telegram_bot_examples/deep_linking__start_argument.py#L25) `https://t.me/<bot>?start=<start_argument>`. Тогда, чтобы бот знал откуда был переход мы можем в `<start_argument>` передавать ссылку на сайт. По-другому не думаю, что можно узнать откуда было открытие ссылки

Comment: А это можно как-то добавить в эту ссылку: tg://resolve?domain=botname

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете реализовать это через параметр `start` - `https://t.me/botname?start=data`, где `data` - это то, что вы хотите передать боту от имени пользователя, который перейдёт по этой ссылке и нажмёт кнопку старта. В боте `data` можно получить из текста сообщения (`message.text.split()[1]`).

Comment: А это можно как-то добавить в эту ссылку: tg://resolve?domain=botname

Comment: @romas, разумеется, `tg://resolve?domain=botname&start=data`.

Comment: При замене `data` на ссылку, бот ничего не выводит

Comment: @romas, помещать полноценную ссылку в `data` - ужасная идея. Вы можете создать словарь, в котором будете хранить айди сайтов и ссылки на них, а в качестве полезной нагрузки передавать телеграмму именно этот айди.

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы он выводил не `data` а что-то из словаря?

пока это всё выглядит у меня так:
`@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text.split()[1])`

Comment: @romas, для этого вы можете создать новый вопрос или же более подробно выучить основы питона.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Только если сайт добавит свой адрес или идентификатор в ссылку: https://t.me/triviabot?start=site_name.
Потом в боте можно обработать полученные данные и отправить обратно пользователю.

https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

Comment: А это можно как-то добавить в эту ссылку: tg://resolve?domain=botname

Comment: @romas, да, как и сам Телеграм делает на странице https://t.me/triviabot?start=site_name -- tg://resolve?domain=triviabot&start=site_name